# Returning a subclass as type interface

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8, interface, java-stream

I am having a problem with a class I am writing for an assignment. I have an interface,  Person, that has 3 abstract methods getID, getFirstName, and getLastName. These return Strings. I have another class called Employee which implements Person. I have a static method, which takes in a line from  a file as a String and instantiates a new object of Employee then returns it as a Person. The only problem is that Employee also has an attribute called salary that Person cannot have, so later when I try to manipulate data on the new objects, I cannot access the salary attribute in the objects. I really don't know any way around this. If any of you can give me any suggestions on this, it would be greatly appreciated. Below you can find the parse method, and the stream I used to create the list, the stream where I attempted to manipulate the salary data, and the interface.

```java
public static Person parse(String s) { 
    String[] empData = s.split(","); 
    Employee hello = new Employee(empData[0], empData[1], empData[2], BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(empData[3]))); 
        
    return hello;
}
```

```java
List<Person> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)) 
    .map(Employee::parse)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
DoubleSummaryStatistics total = stream.stream().mapToDouble((emp) -> Double.parseDouble(emp.salary.toString())).summaryStatistics(); 
            System.out.println("Total average and the total number of employees:");
```

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface Person {
    public String getID(); 
    public String getFirstName(); 
    public String getLastName();
}
```

Comment: There is no use in returning an Employee as a Person in this case. Otherwise you'll have to typecast it to Employee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which takes in a line from a file as a String and instantiates a new object of Employee then returns it as a Person.

Doctor, it hurts when I press here!

Well, stop doing that then.

Return this as a `List<Employee>` instead. The whole point of returning `List<Person>` is that you are free to change your mind later and return non-employees (you have signed up to always return persons, but not neccessarily employees), therefore, javac will not let you presume that they are employees. If you want to carry on and assume: Hey, these are always employees, therefore 'person.getSalary()' is always going to be sensible, then... say that.

If you can't, you can use `instanceof` to check if a person is an employee, and then cast to get the salary:

```
double salary = p instanceof Employee ? ((Employee) p).getSalary() : 0.0;
```

and starting in java15, you can write:

```
double salary = p instanceof Employee e ? e.getSalary() : 0.0;
```

which is a lot prettier...

but that's a very different kind of code: That's saying: For all persons, *IF* they are employee, consider their salary to be whatever the employee object says it is. If not, then count them at 0. If that's what you *WANT*, this code works, but it sounds more like you're confused. Do you have a list of persons, or a list of employees, which one is it?

Comment: What I would love to do is to have parse return Employee and just make a list of Employees. My code works perfectly fine if I do this. Upon further examination of my assignment I found one thing that I neglected, which is that parse has to instantiate an object of type Employee, but return an object of type Person. This isn't a huge deal for most of the code because Employee and Person have methods to return values for most of the attributes. The only attribute Person does not cover is salary, and therein lies my issue, All I would like is to perform the above stream on the list of Persons :/

Comment: @abcdg I'm not sure what you want me to tell you, other than: "Well, the rules of the assignment are stupid, or, you've missed some detail" :P - in actual professional environments you'd just make that return a List<Employee> and move on.

Comment: oh for that I was just clearing up the whole part of myself being confused, was just saying I know the better way to implement this would be to make parse return employee but the reason I cant is because of the constraints of the assignment. Regarding the above implementation, I am uncertain of its placement. Where inside the stream would I implement the above code? I am new to java 8 streams and I have tried to cast the objects in the list during my lambda expressions, but this does not seem to work. Sorry again for the bother, and thank you for all your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: So, this bit: `(emp) -> Double.parseDouble(emp.salary.toString())` needs to become something like `person -> person instanceof Employee ? ((Employee) person).salary.toString() : "0"`.